# How to delete Foreigen key constraint from table in yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, dataprovider

In **actionDelete** I have write query for get fk from all table and create activeDataProvider.and write a foreach loop for geting one by one element.

```
$query = new \yii\db\Query;
        $query->select('practiceCode')->from('member','plan','offer','appointment','product','incentive','clinic','complaint')
        ->where(['practiceCode' => $model->practiceCode])->all();
        $query->createCommand();
        $dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
            'pagination' => false,
       ]);
        $models = $dataProvider->getModels();
        if(count($models) >= 1) {
            $memberModel = new Member();
               foreach ($models as $k) {
                   $k['deleted'] = 'Y';
                  //$memberModel->save();

$connection->createCommand()->update('member', ['deleted' => 'Y'], ['practiceCode' => $models['practiceCode']])->execute();
```

Now it's work Doing same think for all table one by one

```
            }
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
```

I am troubling with how save this Flag 'Y' in all table where this **practiceCode** as foreign key.Please help how to do....Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to delete all the records which contain practiceCode as foreign key ? right ?

Comment: Yes ,I wanna delete all records which contain practiceCode as fk

Comment: so i think you want to use relation to delete it. and currently what error you got ?

Comment: How can i use relation?can you explain

Comment: i.e : $oModel = ModelName::find()->with('originaltable_name')->where(['practiceCode' => $your_value])->all(); 

you will select your records and delete.  you will define your relation using with()

Comment: I have already going through but at time I want to update same value in different table

Comment: one better way is you will define relation in database in "add index" and when you delete main post it will automatically delete all related records of that post

Comment: ok so you want to update that value or delete ? please let me clear what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: @jilesh .. your comment seems useful.  post them like an answer.. could be useful for someone..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i.e : `$oModel = ModelName::find()->with('originaltable_name')->where(['practiceCode' => $your_value])->all();` you will select your records and delete. you will define your relation using with()